# Extract resolves to never

Tags: typescript

I have following code.

```
type EventData<T> =
  | { op: 'INSERT'; data: { new: T } }
  | { op: 'DELETE'; data: { old: T } }
  | { op: 'UPDATE' | 'MANUAL'; data: { new: T; old: T } }

type Operation = EventData<any>['op']

interface EventPayload<T = any> {
  event: EventData<T>
}

type OperationHandler<Op extends Operation> = (
  data: Extract<EventPayload['event'], { op: Op }>['data'],
) => void


const factory = (handlers: { [Op in Operation]?: OperationHandler<Op> }) => {
  return ({ op, data }: EventPayload['event']) => {
    const handler = handlers[op]

    handler?.(data)
  }
}
```

and TypeScript gives me this error

```
Argument of type '{ new: any; } | { old: any; } | { new: any; old: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type '{ new: any; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I can make this work by having

```
const handler = handlers[op] as OperationHandler<Operation>
```

but I don't understand why. Can someone please explain? Thanks in advance.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAIgQ2GgPAFQHxQC8AsAFBRQA%20UA3lAPZgBcUA5AJIByAyjAEo5WAbigATDGhZ1EEAO4scUAL7KyFanUYtWKGABkYOGMLESpDADaiFy1eShkyoSFADykAE4YAlvURFYBGR0TCw0RBA8AG1WRlYAXUdSb2QIDwAzNABjaHgkYAAFNBALejRRXADwyNo1KAgg4BY84IlcPDIlJOdodzSfPwAJcNELNKx3eoAPYCRRAGc3TwHEAkIoAAo68Uxmma8s4CwWwuLS8piG-ISAGloGZiXlaNYdtFuyAEoiAjh6b1ESTIWT882AUEyh3oHhAAQ2AAsRmMPPNzFFJiklv1gL5EPEAPwsPpeHFDJHjdwEJTfQgEGh1DwQYAAVw8-g2mjAdzeymajSKJTKokujQSNLpdQoIMQYKgiMQozSAXlipRUUY8SESQoFBVyPxADoNm9PnUuqQlEA)

Comment: Typescript can't really keep track of  the fact that `handler`  and `data` are corelated. The type of  `handler` will be a union of the type in `handlers` . Since this a union of functions it is only safe to invoke it with an intesection of parameters which in this case resolves to `never`